# How to sort a list that contains combined numerical and text value based on the order of numerical value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have one unsorted list

```
['1 Apple', '6 Apple', '2 Apple', '4 Apple', '3 Apple', '170 Apple', 'category']
```

How can I make a list that values added in a ascending order such that:

```
['category', '1 Apple', '2 Apple', '3 Apple', '4 Apple', '6 Apple', '170 Apple']`
```

Comment: Can it contain negative and/or floats?

Comment: ['1 Apple', '6 Apple', '2 Apple', '4 Apple', '3 Apple', '170 Apple', 'category', 'book']. What is the output you want in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by

`s = sorted(s, key=lambda x:int(x.split(' ')[0]))`

But only when list contains a space and a numeric value before it, as the case is specified by you. For 'category' we can easily differentiate if it follows above described logic or not.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution that should work for any kind of "mixed string-only + number-string element" list.

```
import re
s = ['1Apple', '6 Apple', '2 Apple', '4 Apple', '3 Apple', '170 Apple', 'category']
nums = [re.findall('\d+',ss) for ss in s] # extracts numbers from strings
numsint = [int(*n) for n in nums] # returns 0 for the empty list corresponding to the word
sorted_list = [x for y, x in sorted(zip(numsint, s))] # sorts s based on the sorting of nums2

print(sorted_list)
# output
['category', '1Apple', '2 Apple', '3 Apple', '4 Apple', '6 Apple', '170 Apple']
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use sort or sorted specifying a key that extract that number from strings.

This is a quick example that doesn't handle all corner cases (floats, negatives, no integer ordering) but should be enough for you to get the general idea:

```py
def numeric_key(string):
    splitted = string.split(' ')
    if splitted[0].isdigit():
        return int(splitted[0])
    return -1

my_list.sort(key=numeric_key)
```

Comment: thanks mate! I also tried use a lambda function to get rid of 'apple' which works as well

Comment: the `if splitted` part is unnecessary because [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will always return a non-empty list: even if the string can't be splitted, a list with the original string will be returned

Comment: For full precision: my last comment is true whenever a delimiter is specified. When splitting on a space without explicitly specifying it (equal to passing `None`) an empty list might be returned when splitting the empty string or only spaces. In this case, it will never be an empty list

Answer (score 2):

My way, in one line (works with all mixed types):

```
import re
s=['1 Apple', '6 Apple', '2 Apple', '4 Apple', '3 Apple', '170 Apple', 'category', 'billy']

x=[i[2] for i in sorted([([float(i) for i in (re.findall(r'\d+',i))],re.findall(r'[^0-9]+',i),i) for i in s])]

['billy',
 'category',
 '1 Apple',
 '2 Apple',
 '3 Apple',
 '4 Apple',
 '6 Apple',
 '170 Apple']
```